# Getting Merged documents using CONNECT API

Tags: docusignapi

Currently I am using CONNECT API configured with my system.

Whenever DocuSign Envelope moves to **Completed** status, a POST request is generated to my system which contains:

1. DocuSign Envelope information
2. DocuSign PDF bytes ( Seperate PDF documents )
3. DocuSign certificate

I selected the option [X] Include Documents in Connect API and I am able to receive the PDF bytes.
Currently I am using **PDFTK** to merge all the documents into one.

But is there a way using Connect API to get all the Documents merged together as a **one Single PDF document** ?

Parallely while reading through the DocuSign REST API guide I came across /envelope/id?merge=true which would give me the required single PDF. But while digging deeper I came to know there is a concept called **Integrator Key** for each implementation, which would require a DocuSign Certification.

Inorder to just get a merged document instead of seperate PDF documents should I go through this certification process or is there a simple way to do the same ?

If Certification is Mandatory then what kind of certification would this fall in, because I have no front end application for signing process and I am just consuming the customer generated documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DocuSign Connect does not require an **IntegratorKey** or that you go through the DocuSign API Certification process.  The Certification Process (https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification) and Integrator Key exist to ensure that DocuSign customers who utilize either the **REST API** or the **SOAP API** are not doing anything that could be harmful to the overall DocuSign service -- this is not relevant to DocuSign Connect, since Connect is merely pushing data to your listener when Envelope events occur (i.e., you're not explicitly polling DocuSign for changes, as you might with either the REST API or SOAP API).

I don't believe it's possible to configure Connect such that documents are sent merged together as one file; they're always going to be sent as separate files in the Connect message. It would be feasible to, during your processing of the Connect XML message, make a REST API call to DocuSign to request the Envelope's documents in a single file -- however, doing so would require that you use an Integrator Key, and that you go through the DocuSign API Certification process -- probably not worth the time, expense, and trouble, if there's another way for you to merge the files yourself.